# Как скрыть блок для всей категории с помощью php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Недавно задавала вопрос насчет скрытия блока с помощью кода

```
<?php if (in_array('otzivi', explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) { ?>
    <style>
        #news {display:none;}
        #otzivi {display:none;}
        #podelitsya {display:none;}
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

Мне объяснили, что функция explode разбивает урл по разделителю "/" и делает из полученных данных массив, и затем с помощью in_array идет проверка, есть ли в урл otzivi. Теперь мне нужно сделать то же самое для категории новостей, но здесь другой урл вида index.php/novosti?start=4 - очевидно из-за того, что не получается выделить novosti, код не срабатывает. Как правильно выделить novosti из урл, чтобы код сработал? И пожалуйста, если напишете ответ, объясните, что делает та или иная функция, хотелось бы понимать, как работает код. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Любой роутинг по url-у строится на regexp-ах, либо абстракцией над ними с использованием плейсхолдеров (небольшое снижение сложности восприятия regex-ов): [chriso/klein.php](http://goo.gl/wgyQBi)
, [nikic/FastRoute](http://goo.gl/7ENZzX), [laravel route](https://laravel.ru/docs/v4/routing).

Если коротко, то под капотом у них происходит следующее:

```
preg_match('/^\/index.php\/(?P<category>[\w-]+)/', '/index.php/novosti/?start=4', $matches);
var_dump($matches['category']); // result: novosti
```

И так на каждое правило.

Кроме того, API данных библиотек предоставляет проверку request-метода (GET, POST, PUT  и т.д.) и иных параметров заголовка (к примеру, isAjax()), автоматом строит правила для REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Перестаньте удалять гланды через задний проход!

Если нужно, то просто вешайте на блок display:none через тот же jQuery.

Comment: Отличный подход. Сначала загрузить данные, потом скрыть их с помощью jQuery. А не проще вообще их не загружать, траффик не резиновый?

Comment: @Magos а не лучше ли тогда не пытаться их "скрывать\прятать" и тд, а просто напросто выводить только то, что нужно, не настраивая километры if-ов. 
Тем более тут, как я понял, это дело всё равно грузится, просто на него с сервера вешается свойство display:none

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'novosti')) { ?>
    <style>
        #novosti {display:none;}
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

В `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` содержит имя скрипта, начиная от корневой директории виртуального хоста, и параметры.

strpos — возвращает позицию первого вхождения подстроки.

То есть если в строке `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` есть подстрока `novosti`, то он скроет блок.

Comment: К сожалению, `index.php/monovostik` тоже подпадает под это условие.

И `if (strpos(...))` лучше не использовать - `strpos` может вернуть 0 (т.е. найдено в самом начале строки), поэтому сравнивать стоит с FALSE (читай [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php))